# Referencing a ViewController in AppDelegate - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to get a `NSMutableArray` from another class.  I am trying to reference that ViewController that contains the array.  Lets say, `a` has the array I want.  `b` is the class I am going to get that array in.

a.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *selectedCells;
```

a.m:

```
@synthesize selectedCells;
```

AppDelegate.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) a *create_challengeDelegate;
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
@synthesize create_challengeDelegate;
a *create_challengeDelegate = [[a alloc]init];
```

Right here when I try to reference that ViewController I get an error saying:

```
Initializer element is not a compile-time constant
```

I assume it has something to do with it not being able to see the ViewController.

In my b.m:

```
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
app.create_challengeDelegate.selectedCells
```

My issue is working with initializing the ViewController in the delegate.

Suggestions and thoughts on that?

Comment: hopefully you are not forgetting `#import "a.h"` in `AppDelegate.h`

Comment: @faisalali I am not, I am including #import in the appdelegate.h

Comment: Where exactly and when (xcode, compile, runtime) to you get the error?

Comment: @hermannKlecker excatly the error I gave

Comment: Post the init method for the view controller.

Comment: A minor comment:Why bother creating a property and using `@synthesize` (which is not required) when you are not using the `self.` property accessor? Also, you can't `alloc init` the `create_challengeDelegate` directly after the `@synthesize` - it must be in a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is that you create the `selectedCells` array in you `AppDelegate` and send it to `A`. E.g. in:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *selectedCells;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.selectedCells = [NSMutableArray array];

    A *viewA = [[a alloc] initWithNibName:@"a" bundle:nil selectedCells:self.selectedCells];

    [...]
}
```

**a.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedCells;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil selectedCells:(NSMutableArray*)cells;
```

**a.m**

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil selectedCells:(NSMutableArray*)cells
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.selectedCells = cells;
    }
    return self;
}
```

**b.m**

```
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSMutableArray *selectedCells = app.selectedCells;
```

This way, whenever you make changes to `selectedCells` it will keep it in the array you send there since `selectedCells` is a refference to an object which is created in your `AppDelegate`.

Otherwise, what you are trying to do is access a view which might no longer be available in the memory since the view might have been deallocated. 
Also, you create the instance of `a` but its not set to the `AppDelegate`'s instance of `a`, its a seperate instance.

Instead of

```
@synthesize create_challengeDelegate;
a *create_challengeDelegate = [[a alloc]init];
```

You should have

```
@synthesize create_challengeDelegate;
self.create_challengeDelegate = [[a alloc] init];
```

I still strongly recommend you do not access your view this way though.

*P.s. `@synthesize` is no longer necessary.*

***Edit***
This is a better solution.

*Selection.h*

```
/**
 *  The entity for selections
 */
@interface Selection : NSObject

/**
 *  The Shared Instance
 *
 *  @return Selection The instance
 */
+ (Selection *)sharedInstance;

/**
 *  Add an item to the selections
 *
 *  @param object id The object to add
 */
- (void)addSelection:(id)object;

/**
 *  Remove an item from the selections
 *
 *  @param object id The object to remove
 */
- (void)removeObject:(id)object;

/**
 *  Get the selections
 *
 *  @return NSArray The array with the current selection objects
 */
- (NSArray *)getSelections;

@end
```

*Selection.m*

```
#import "Selection.h"

@interface Selection ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selections;

@end

@implementation Selection

#pragma mark - Public methods

+ (Selection *)sharedInstance
{
    static Selection *sharedInstance = nil;

    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

#pragma mark - Private methods

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.selections = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Manage selection

- (void)addSelection:(id)object
{
    [self.selections addObject:object];
}

- (void)removeObject:(id)object
{
    [self.selections removeOjbect:object];
}

- (NSArray *)getSelections
{
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.selections];
}
```

Now you can assess your shared singeton in `A` and/or `B` by accessing:

```
[[Selection sharedInstance] addObject:myObject];

[[Selection sharedInstance] removeObject:myObject];

NSArray *array = [[Selection sharedInstance] getSelections];
```

Comment: selectedCells is being used inside a view controller, and from its name it implies its maybe it associated with a table view, just the term "selected" on its own implies something to do with user interaction. Hence I would respectfully disagree that it should go into the app delegate, firstly the app delegate is too often a dumping ground, but secondly if selectedCells is just a GUI display related data structure then it should be kept in the view controller in my humble opinion (note, I'm making a distinction between data structures in general and GUI display related data structures)

Comment: This returns null for me

Comment: @Piepants You make a valid argument and I agree with you. Preferably one should use a shared singleton for keeping shared data. However, accessing VC `a` from `b` through `AppDelegate` is a even worst solution then the one I mention above. Especially when using `ARC`.

Comment: @DavidBiga I updated my answer with a better solution then adding it to your `AppDelegate`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this line inside a method:

```
a *create_challengeDelegate = [[a alloc]init];
```

If not that would probably explain your issue. If that's not the problem it might be helpful to post more complete code.

Comment: no It was not, I put it inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`